# Jenkins and Kubernetes Design Involving GitHub

Tags: jenkins, github, kubernetes, webhooks, persistent-volumes

I am currently designing a system that involves integrating GitHub webhooks with Jenkins in a Kubernetes environment, and I would like to see whether this is feasible or not.

Currently, I have a GitHub repository setup with some code. In Kubernetes, we have a volume setup where we plan to clone said repository into this volume. This repository will need to be up-to-date at all times, but we shouldn't manually update this repository every time a change is made. With Jenkins, we want to setup webhooks in GitHub so any time changes made in the code repository will be updated in the volume.

I am still new to the idea of webhooks and Jenkins will interact in a Kubernetes environment, specifically a volume, so any thoughts and comments would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might have more luck with with an answer over at https://devops.stackexchange.com/. Apart from that, it sounds like a perfectly doable endeavor, I wouldn't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks - I went ahead and reposted the question there.